# Mapping table in Kafka Flink to convert units

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, data-conversion

I would like to understand if there is something similar to a mapping table in kafka or Flink.

I have producers and they will get data.

I would like to have the possibility to convert this data to a range of unit.

I am desperately looking for a "mapping table" experience which would enable to check if the producer is getting a specific data in a specific unit and convert if this is the case.

I want to have some embedded flexibility to be reactive afterwards, and change it if needed in the future.

I have been looking a micronauts which is interesting but as nothing to do with this, or anything which could help.
If someone has a perspective on this, I would be glad.

Lets provide an extract of a typical SQL example. In this example, I have a "Measurement unit" table which is enabling me to do things quickly, so whatever unit I have I can convert it and change it quickly.

```
   create table unit_unit_conv(
   from_unit varchar(10)   not null
  ,to_unit   varchar(10)   not null
  ,rate      decimal(10,6) not null
  ,primary key(from_unit, to_unit)
);

insert into unit_unit_conv values('kilogram', 'kilogram',   1);
insert into unit_unit_conv values('kilogram', 'gram',       1000);
insert into unit_unit_conv values('kilogram', 'box',        0.2);
insert into unit_unit_conv values('gram',     'gram',       1);
insert into unit_unit_conv values('gram',     'kilogram',   0.001);
insert into unit_unit_conv values('gram',     'box',        0.0002);
insert into unit_unit_conv values('box',      'box',        1);
insert into unit_unit_conv values('box',      'kilogram',   5);
insert into unit_unit_conv values('box',      'gram',       5000);
```

I would be really glad to find this same thing in Kafka, with a "master producer" in a way checking the others and checking their units and performing conversions by referring to his "own" fixed knowledge.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example that illustrates the problem to be solved and how such a "mapping table" might be used to solve the problem?

Comment: wouldn't flink's `map` or `flatmap` do what you need? I'm not sure if I understand the issue. Where is the mapping stored?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I do not map or flatmap and I will try adding elements to my question.

Comment: Seems like you could do exactly that with Flink SQL.

Comment: Thank you I will try to look it up. Could you provide more information on Flink SQL?